# How to make a for loop keep returning values?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, return, negative-number

I have to set up two loops. One that keeps totaling the number of negative numbers in a list and is returned. Another that appends the negatives to a separate list to also be returned. I have only been able to return the first value in each loop.

```
# Given the parameter list, returns the count of negative numbers in the list
def num_negatives(list):
    negatives = 0
    for neg in list:
        if neg < 0:
            negatives += 1
            return negatives

# Given the parameter list, returns a list that contains only the negative numbers in the parameter list 
def negatives(list):    
    negList = []
    for negItems in list:
        if negItems < 0:
            negList.append(negItems)
            return negList    

# Prompts the user to enter a list of numbers and store them in a list
list = [float(x) for x in input('Enter some numbers separated by whitespace ').split()]
print() 

# Output the number of negatives in the list
print('The number of negatives in the list is', num_negatives(list))
print()

# output the list of negatives numbers    
print('The negatives in the list are ', end = '') 

for items in negatives(list):
    print(items, ' ', sep = '', end = '')     
print('\n')
```

If I were to put in the values `1 2 3 4 5 -6 7 -8 9 -12.7` at the start of the program, I should receive this.

```
The number of negatives in the list is 3

The negatives in the list are -6.0 -8.0 -12.7
```

Instead, I only get:

```
The number of negatives in the list is 1

The negatives in the list are -6.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have your returns in the wrong locations. You don't want to return multiple times. You just want to return the final value **once** when your function is done running. So your functions should be like this:

```
# Find number of negative numbers in the list
def num_negatives(list):
    negatives = 0
    for neg in list:
        if neg < 0:
            negatives += 1
    return negatives

def negatives(list):    
    negList = []
    for negItems in list:
        if negItems < 0:
            negList.append(negItems)
    return negList
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're searching for `yield` which is an elegant solution for creating iterables.

```
def num_negatives(list):
    negatives = 0
    for neg in list:
        if neg < 0:
            yield neg  # I return the negative number directly.

def negatives(list): 
    negList = []   
    negatives_generator = num_negatives(list)
    for negItem in negatives_generator:
        negList.append(negItem)
    return negList
```

Then finally you can print the negatives list and `len(negatives)`, you have both now.

For more details: [What does yield do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/what-does-the-yield-keyword-do)

Comment: While this is a useful tool, it does not address OP's situation, which appears to deal with a homework question that expects a specific approach.